# How do you derive the formula for the natural logarithm using the definition of the number $e$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Using the fact that the number e is specifically chosen to satisfy the differential equation $\frac{d(e^x)}{dx} = e^x$ it's pretty easy to see that $e = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ (or at least, I could derive this.)

It's pretty well known that when you end up differentiating an exponential function $f(x) = n^x$, you get $f'(x)=n^x\ln(n)$

If $f(x) = f'(x)$, then $\ln(n)=1$, and $n=e$, which is consistent.

Using the standard definition of the derivative, for $f(x) = n^x$, you end up getting

$$f'(x)=n^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$$

This implies that

$$\ln(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$$

but how do you prove this (which will also end up proving that differential rule stated above, and will also prove that $e^{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}}=x$)

Comment: You can prove it with L'Hopital, of course, using the derivative you've found above. But if you define $\ln(x)$ this way, you need to go backwards.

Comment: If $x=e^y,$ then $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{yh}-1}{h}$ is the derivative of $e^{yt}$ at $t=0,$ which is $y.$ So if $f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}h,$ then $f(e^y)=y.$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. If you know that $f'(x)=n^x \cdot \ln(n)$, and also that $f'(x)=n^x\cdot \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{n^h-1}{h}$, then it follows that $n^x\cdot \ln(n)=n^x\cdot \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{n^h-1}{h}$ for all $x$. Since $n^x\neq0$ for any $x$, we can divide both sides by $n^x$ and obtain the desired result. This *is* a proof.

Comment: How do you define $\ln(x)$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$? One definition is to define $\ln : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ as the inverse of $\exp : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$. With this definition, the inverse function theorem implies that $\ln$ is smooth and $\ln'(x) = 1/x$. Using this, you can prove the differential rule for $n^x = e^{x\ln(n)}$,  and hence the limit formula for $\ln$.

Comment: But really, you've literally done just what you asked for in the title inside your question.

Comment: You're right that, if we don't assume any derivative formulas yet, the derivation of $\ln x = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{x^h-1}h$ is not at all clear. [It's not too hard to show](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~CLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/subsection-22.html) that $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{x^h-1}h = \log_y x$ for some fixed constant $y$; the hard part is showing that $y=e$. Indeed, sometimes $e$ is *defined* as the unique positive constant that satisfies $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h-1}h = 1$.

Comment: As you have described the question, it is not clear what you assume and what you want to prove. Please clarify the question. Say, "I assume this and I want to prove that"!

Comment: I assume the definition of e, I **don't** assume any derivative formulas, and I want to prove that $ln(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=n^x\qquad n>0\\
f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{n^{x+h}-n^x}{h}\\
f'(x)=n^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{n^h-1}{h}\\
L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{n^h-1}{h}\\
L=\ln n\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h\ln n}-1}{h\ln n}$$
Now substitute:
$$t:=h\ln n\\
t\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad h\to 0\\
L=\ln n\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
Notice by the definition of $e$:
$$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=e^x\\
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1\\
L=\ln n\\
f'(x)=n^x\ln n$$